# listing with labeled frame

Tags: listings

I'm trying to get 'labeled' frames on an `lstlisting` environment that looks like this:

[image]

The top and bottom frames are easy are fairly easy to achieve:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=tb]
  Code 
  Code 
  Code
\end{lstlisting}
```

But after perusing through the listings documentation, I'm unsure how to achieve the "Some Text" labels on the bottom and top frames (it seems that kind of thing is not supported).

I've looked to alternative packages such as `mdframed` and `fancyvrb`. `fancyvrb` comes close to what I'm looking for, but from what I can by the options only allows the "Some Text" labels to be aligned in the center, i.e.:

[image]

Also, one consideration: I already have a nice (and working) `lst` style definition for my language, so It'd be nice if any solution to this could still using `lstlisting` (and hence my language definition).

Comment: Check the tcolorbox documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A version with `tcolorbox` and its `listings` library (which was my first idea to realize this)

The appearance can be changed by styles or by changing the `overlay` portion of the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newtcblisting[auto counter]{somecode}[2][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  boxrule=0pt,
  toprule=1pt,
  bottomrule=1pt,
  listing options={language={C}},
  listing only,
  colback=white,
  sharp corners,
  overlay={\node[inner sep=2pt,xshift=-2cm,fill=tcbcol@back] (A) at (frame.south east) {#2};
           \node[inner sep=2pt,xshift=+2cm,fill=tcbcol@back] (B) at (frame.north west) {#2};
  },
  #1,
}
\makeatother





\begin{document}

\begin{somecode}{Some Text}
int main
\end{somecode}

\begin{somecode}[colback=yellow!10!white]{Some Text}
int main
\end{somecode}

\end{document}
```

[image]